# Do i have to delete unused views on backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, backbone-views

```
var Home = Backbone.View.extend({
template: _.template($('#home-template').html()),

initialize: function (params) {
    this.collection = new BlogList();

    this.listenTo(this.collection, "add", this.renderBlog);
    this.listenTo(this.collection, "reset", this.render);
},

render: function () {
    this.$el.html(this.template({hasPrevious: this.collection.hasPrevious()}));

    this.collection.each(function(item) {
        this.renderBlog(item);
    }, this);

    return this;
},

renderBlog: function(item) {
    this.$('#blog-list-container').append((new BlogPreView({ model: item })).render().el);
},
```

BlogPreView is a Backbone.View
A new BlogPreView is instantiated many times. Do i need to delete the old ones.

How to delete a backbone.view and how do i delete in this specific example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be calling [`remove`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-remove) on your views to remove them. That will remove the `el` from the DOM and call [`stopListening`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-stopListening) to undo any `listenTo` calls you've made. If there are other things to clean up, then you should override `remove` to clean up these "other things" and then call the standard `remove`.

In your case, you have child views so you should keep track of them:

```
renderBlog: function(item) {
    var v = new BlogPreView({ model: item });
    this.previews.push(v); // Initialize this in `initialize` of course.
    this.$('#blog-list-container').append(v.render().el);
}
```

and then clean them up before re-rendering or removing:

```
removePreviews: function() {
    _(this.previews).invoke('remove');
    this.previews = [ ];
},
render: function() {
    this.removePreviews();
    // what you have now goes here...
},
remove: function() {
    this.removePreviews();
    return Backbone.View.prototype.remove.apply(this);
}
```

You can often get away without calling `remove` but once you discover that you do need it, it can be a massive hassle to retrofit your code to `remove` things properly. But if you call `remove` all the time, properly track subviews, and override `remove` as needed then you won't get stuck doing an unpleasant retrofit later.